# monit error with exec code

Tags: exec, nohup, monit

It is a monit conf file /etc/monit.d/file.conf

```js
check process python
    matching "python"
    if failed
    exec "/usr/bin/nohup ./path to a.py 2>/dev/null &"
    exec "/usr/bin/killall -9 python"
    if uptime > 3 minutes then
```

I get a syntax error in line 4 : /etc/monit.d/python:4: Error: syntax error 'exec "'
Anything I'm doing wrong?
could someone suggest the easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You missed `then` after `if failed`:

```
if failed then
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that exec is the right keyword to use.
Here is a personal example on how to start a process and *monit*or it:

```
check process mako matching "mako.conf"
    start program = "/usr/bin/mako -d -c /home/pi/mako/mako.conf"
    stop program  = "/usr/bin/killall mako"
    if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Regards